# how do i load text smoothly in kivy's gui

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I created a virtual assistant using kivy, its almost working other than displaying the text automatically and smoothly on the label I have given command to.
it loads the current line when I click on maximize or minimize button

## this is code of .kv file

```
<MySiri>:
id:siri
display:entry
padding:10
spacing:10
orientation:'vertical'
Label:
    id:entry
    text:'THIS IS PYTHON ASSISTANT'
    font_size:40
    valign:'middle'
Button:
    text:"START ASSISTANT"
    on_release:entry.text="STARTNING ASSISTANT"
    on_press:siri.startAssistant()e
```

Comment: What do you mean *smoothly* in this case?

Comment: I meant that label should load the text but its only loading when I click on minimize or maximize ,i.e minimizing or maximizing the framework

Comment: provide a [mRE]

Comment: ``` if 'music' in command:
            self.display.text = "Please wait while I play music for you."
            self.speak("Please wait while I play music for you.")
            self.playMusic()
            self.main() ```

Comment: music will be played but wont display the line that is proved to the label until I help kivy to refresh by clicking on maximize or minimize button @eyllanesc

Comment: again, provide an MRE